# element jumps on $('#cart_table').css("top", $('#cart_table').css('top'));

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is html

```
<div id="cart_table" style="width:800px; position:absolute;">
    <h3>My Cart</h3>
    Please check your shipping data and press "Place Order" to complete this order
</div>
```

And javascript

```
var cartTableTop = parseInt($('#cart_table').css('top'));
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#remove').html(cartTableTop) // just to debug
    $('#cart_table').css("top", (cartTableTop) + "px");
    $('#remove').html($('#remove').html()+' '+$('#cart_table').css('top'))// just to debug
});
```

`cartTableTop` == $('#cart_table').css('top') but  `#cart_table` jumps down after scroll. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a jsfiddle out of your code, and I don't see any jumping: http://jsfiddle.net/qZJdB/1/. So, the problem is probably elsewhere in the code.

Also, I don't understand that debuging bit... `#remove` is not being rendered.